# Ture/false check question about Unique basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am studying linear algebra with the textbook written by Gilbert Strang.

In the textbook, there is a true or false question:

- The row space of $A$ has a unique basis that can be computed by reducing $A$ to echelon form.

I think all matrix $A$ have many bases except for matrices defined over integer field modulo $2$. Thus, I consider this statement as being FALSE.

Please let me know this statement is true or false.
Also, is my reason for falsity of the statement valid if it is false?

Answer (score 1):

The row space of $A$ has a **unique basis that can be computed by reducing $A$ to echelon form**.

It means that whenever you reduce $A$ to RREF, you only obtain one basis.

It is not claiming that there is only one possible basis.

Comment: You mean the statement is true?

Comment: Yes.$ $$ $$ $$ $

Comment: I am really sorry but can you give me some example? I do not understand why there is only ONE basis.

Comment: @Danny_Kim there is only ONE basis which is produced by the RREF. The other basis are not produced by the RREF.

Comment: The statement did not say reduced echelon form, just it said reducing the matrix to echelon form. In this case, is there only one basis?

Comment: @Danny_Kim how can you **reduce** a matrix into **unreduced** echelon form @_@ there is only one basis that is produced in the RREF, because RREF is unique.

Comment: I give you an example. If $A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1&1\\2&4&7\end{array}\right]$, then the echelon form of $A$ is $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1&1\\0&2&5\end{array}\right]$, but the reduced echelon form of $A$ is $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0&-1.5\\0&1&2.5\end{array}\right]$.